# How to find string's left , right, middle side in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to divide my NameSurname variable to take name and surname seperately. How can I use left, right methods for this?

```
public ActionResult SearchPerson(string NameSurname)
       {
            VisitService srv = new VisitService(user);
            List<PersonListViewModel> result = null;
            var filters = SearchFilterHelper.EmptySearchFilter();
            if(!NameSurname.IsBlank()) 
            { 
            filters.AddLike("Person.Name", NameSurname);
                
               result= srv.GetPersonList(filters);
            }
 
            return PartialView(result);
        }
```

Comment: Why you allow that both information are provided in a single variable?

Comment: @TimSchmelter This is what my team asked me to do.

Comment: Ask your team to provide two separate values.

Comment: If you want to support all cultures and "strange" names, it's a really hard task. It's better to let the user input those on separate fields.

Comment: @msırem: then ask your team why they don't fix the core problem and provide for example separate input fields for name and surname.

Comment: @Fildor they don't accept it. They told me to use this methods but I don't know how.

Comment: Then bail out. This is an unsolvable task. Any "solution" will be sub-par in some respect or another to having simply two separate fields for surname and given name. If they insist, they shall give _exact_ specifications on how to do it.

Comment: @Fildor  and TimSchmelter thank you both for your interest.

Comment: You're welcome. This is one of those cases, where I am highly suspicious of the team. If they are not willing to make a change _that easy_ then _maybe_ something is fundamentally wrong with the team, the codebase or both.

Comment: Wish I have an idea, this is my first job since graduate so I'm a newbie...

Comment: If you absolutely must do this, then you could use `string[] names = string.Split(' ', NameSurname);` which would result in the the first name in `names[0]` and the second name (if any) in `names[1]`. But beware: If the name string doesn't contain any space, you'd only get a single string, and if it contained two spaces (e.g. "John Fred Smith") you'd get three strings in the result. As others have pointed out, these possibilities are going to cause issues.

Comment: Let alone c# solution, even logical solution is not possible for this problem if the input name doesn't have any constraints. For example If the input name has space as delimiter to separate different name parts then you can split the string by space. But if it is going to be a simple string then there is no solution.

Comment: How would you split *John Fitzgerald Kennedy*? How do you know which parts belongs to which group? You can't know, because the middle part could match any side. You could guess, but for every case you'll find a counter example. So it is not solvable without getting wrong results.